# "would like to have Vpp" or "would have liked to V"

Tags: infinitives, perfect-aspect

Suppose you were reading a dictionary that wasn't available when you were a student. Which of the following forms would you use?

> This dictionary is excellent. I **would like to have had** a copy when I was a student. / I **would have liked to have** a copy when I was a student.

Comment: Ooft, that's a good one and, to my eyes, a tough one! I mean, there are other options, such as: "I would have liked to have had..." or even something like "I wish I had had..." (which could be phrased using a contraction, "I wish I'd had..."). Looking forward to an answer -- ideally one that not only says which form is correct, but also explains why,

Answer (score -1):

Q.

> **Suppose you were reading a dictionary that wasn't available when you were a student. Which of the following forms would you use?**

---

> This dictionary is excellent. I would like to have had a copy when I was a student. / I would have liked to have a copy when I was a student.

---

A. **I would not use either.**

*"This dictionary is excellent. I would have liked one, when I was a student"*. Is a better sentence but still sounds awkward and has what I presume are unintended implications. **Note** using a copy here is not needed as no doubt you wanted a dictionary not a photostat copy of the dictionary. I am also using One as a pronoun for the noun dictionary.

So lets switch and change it around a bit.

**This dictionary is excellent, it's a pity I didn't have one when I was a student**

**I would have liked one**, when I was a student or any of your similar sentences implies that you knew about the dictionary when you were a student but did not obtain one. I presume that when you used "I would have liked one" you are trying to imply regret that you did not have one. Therefore we can do just that in a more direct manner "**it's a pity" implies regret**. With this use, you are making both a more direct and a more neutral sentence by "*regretting you did not have one*", without any implication of if you knew of the existence of the dictionary.

---

**Note**

> **would have liked**
> ...should invariably be followed by a present-tense infinitive — hence would have liked to go, would have liked to read, not ✳would have liked to have gone, ✳would have liked to have read.

---

**pity**, noun; If something is described as a pity, it is disappointing or not satisfactory:

It's a pity (that) children spend so little time outside nowadays.

Ref CED [Pity](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pity)

Comment: But doesn't this avoid, rather than answer the question? As I read it, the question is precisely about constructing the correct tenses for the words involved.

Comment: @tkp; Without directly answering your question. This is" English language learners web site" so should I try to help them learn the language or just dogmatically answer the question, even if I cannot correctly do that, because the Question or sentence is not correct usage of our language?

Comment: @tkp Now to directly answer your question. The part of the Question qualifier "that wasn't available when you were a student" negates both of the proposed replies. As they both suggest that the student wanted one.

Comment: A 'copy' of a book does _not_ refer to a photocopy! It is the standard term for one physical example of a printed book, magazine etc. The OP used it correctly.

Comment: @ Kate Bunting, Yes I aware of that, I also said it was not needed, I did not say it was incorrect. By implication he wanted a dictionary so you do not need to say you need a copy of a dictionary, however if you wanted an Photostatted copy of the said dictionary you would need to say copy. The point being I was simplifying the sentence by removing the use of copy.